# Nested Model - Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a scenario, where persons can have multiple address. Showing address type in dropdown, when select address type full address is shown on text area.

```
<div *ngFor="let person of persons">

  <select [ngModel]="selectedAddress" (ngModelChange)="selectedAddress = $event">
     <option *ngFor="let address of person.addresses" [ngValue]="address">
         {{address.type}}
     </option>
  </select>

   <textarea [(ngModel)]="selectedAddress.address"></textarea>

</div>
```

Each person is displayed in each div block. when selecting drop down value on one block populates the text area in other blocks also.

When selecting drop down on one block should populate text area only inside the block. How to handle this scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to handle it with an array of selected address'es. This would be like so - where `selectedAddress` is an array:

```
<div *ngFor="let person of persons; let i = index">
  <select [ngModel]="selectedAddress[i]" (ngModelChange)="selectedAddress[i] = $event">
    <option *ngFor="let address of person.addresses" [ngValue]="address">
        {{address.type}}
    </option>
  </select>
  <textarea [(ngModel)]="selectedAddress[i].address"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Pujol Ferriol  - I get this when i try to implement your suggestion. ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null. Is there any type of null check i am missing.

Comment: You have to initiate the selectAddress array in your component.ts. for exaple like this: private selectedAddress = []

Comment: Is it possible to handle two dimension array scenario. For example, in case if my object is of model selectedAddress = [][]

Comment: My next question over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46899580/array-of-array-model-angular-2